# Upload images to server from Android

Tags: android, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image to a server using MultipartEntity.
While following every tip and answer, I still have the problem of NoClassDefFoundError when running StringBody and FileBody coded lines.
I saw many answers about it but none helped me so far.

Below is the simple AsyncTask class I am using. Also, my dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:project:7'
}
```

My code is:

```
public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    File file;
    String name;

    public UploadImage(File file, String name) {
        this.file = file;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();


        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constants.UPLOAD_URL);

        try
        {

            MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            multipartEntity.addPart("name",new StringBody("myImage"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("image", new FileBody(file));

            post.setEntity(multipartEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }


        }catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the Logcat I get:

```
   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    09-20 13:35:55.515    9866-9977/com.seesharp.agentsreports E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.Consts
                at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody.<init>(StringBody.java:147)
                at com.doron.agentsreports.UploadImage.doInBackground(UploadImage.java:46)
                at com.doron.agentsreports.UploadImage.doInBackground(UploadImage.java:22)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Great first time question!

Comment: can you all the logcat so I can help

Comment: Here is the Logcat I Get